# Custom (Real) Vehicle interface advice Python vs C++

Tags: ros, ros-melodic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hey guys,

I wrote a custom node that subscribes to the accel, brake and steer commands outputted by autoware and routes it to a custom PCB (via USB) that we designed which has manual and remote emergency stops and converts the digital signals to analog signals for the installed drive by wire system (old aevit system). Most code in autoware is written in C++ but i used python as it was just easier for me to do.

Question:

Is there any real benefit by using C++ in this case? I am aware it may be better with time sensitive data but since linux is already not a real-time system does it matter?

Thanks!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/357839/custom-(real)-vehicle-interface-advice-python-vs-c++/) by [JoloGermanAg](https://answers.ros.org/users/53396/jologermanag/) on ROS Answers with karma: 123 on 2020-07-22

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

C++ is faster, certifiable (if you follow certification rules), and allows you to control memory allocations. Python is not suitable for a safety critical application that most robot / AV systems fall under, and without additional profiling could crash from a typo at runtime. If you’re working only in simulation you can do anything you’d like, but if it touches hardware, I highly recommend rewriting in C++

---

Originally posted by [stevemacenski](https://answers.ros.org/users/25940/stevemacenski/) with karma: 8272 on 2020-07-23

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [JoloGermanAg](https://answers.ros.org/users/53396/jologermanag/) on 2020-07-23**:
Thanks, that certainly makes sense. Since this is on a real vehicle I will switch to C++, probably will just use python for some initial debugging with the vehicle on jack stands since it's already up and running. Are there any resources that outline proper code procedure/flow for interface nodes in ROS/C++ ?